# Sort array and rebuild it

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have this array:

```
    $all = array(
            'meat' => Object(
                        'name' => 'meat',
                        'color' => 'red',
                        'class' => 'food'
                ),
            'chicken' => Object(
                        'name' => 'chicken',
                        'color' => 'white',
                        'class' => 'food'
                ),
            'apple' => Object(
                        'name' => 'apple',
                        'color' => 'green',
                        'class' => 'Fruit'
                ),
            'blueberry' => Object(
                        'name' => 'blueberry',
                        'color' => 'blue',
                        'class' => 'Fruit'
                )
    );
```

and i want to Sort it and rebuild it to be like this:

```
    $theright = array(
                array(
                    'class' => 'food',
                    'menu' => array(
                                array(
                                    'name' => 'meat',
                                    'color' => 'red',
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'name' => 'chicken',
                                    'color' => 'white',
                                )

                            )
                    ),
                array(
                    'class' => 'Fruit',
                    'menu' => array(
                                array(
                                    'name' => 'apple',
                                    'color' => 'green',
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'name' => 'blueberry',
                                    'color' => 'blue',
                                )
                        )
                    )
            );
```

I tried to Collect all classes in`$all` array then compare each value with `$all` array:

```
$classArray = array();
foreach($all as $key => $value) {
    $classArray[$value->class] = array();
}
foreach($classArray as $key => $value) {
    $theright[] = array('class' => $key, 'menu' => array());
}
```

this code get me this array:

```
$theright = array(
                array(
                    'class' => 'food',
                    'menu' => array()
                    ),
                array(
                    'class' => 'Fruit',
                    'menu' => array()
                    )
            );
```

and i stop here , how to complete it ?

Comment: You are only using arrays... why are you using object notation (`->`) in your `foreach` loop?

Comment: `$all` is contain Objects . sorry i edit it

Comment: Those are not objects...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use the class as a key to group them together. Example:

```
$food = array();
// gather class
foreach($all as $item) {
    if(!isset($food[$item->class])) {
        $food[$item->class] = array(
            'class' => $item->class,
            'menu' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => $item->name,
                    'color' => $item->name,
                )
            )
        );
    } else {
        $food[$item->class]['menu'][] = array('name' => $item->name,'color' => $item->color,);
    }
}

// simple reindex
$food = array_values($food);
```

Comment: @AdamMo. what do you mean without keys? thats why i used `array_values` in the end to remove those keys on the parent array

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a second loop. This should do what you want.

```
$classMap = array();

foreach ($all as $item)
{
    // check if class has been created in the class map
    if ( ! array_key_exists($classMap, $item['class']))
    {
        $classMap[$item['class']] = array(
            'class' => $item['class'],
            'menu'  => array()
        );
    }

    $classMap[$item['class']]['menu'][] = array(
        'name'  => $item['name'],
        'color' => $item['color']
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with less loop counts (2)

```
$all = [];

function getSelectClassData(array &$all)
{
    $finalArr = [];

    while (count($all) > 1) {
        $res             = [];
        $class           = array_values($all)[0]->class;
        $selectedDataArr = getSelectSimilerMenuData($all, $class);
        $res['class']    = $class;
        $res['menu']     = array_values($selectedDataArr);
        $all             = array_diff_key($all,array_flip(array_keys($selectedDataArr)));
        $finalArr[]      = $res;
    }

    return $finalArr;
}

function getSelectSimilerMenuData(array $all, $class) 
{
    return array_filter(
        $all,
        function ($e) use ($class) {
            return $e->class == $class;
        }
    );
}

print_r(getSelectClassData($all));
```